# ct.fillStyle место в коде

Tags: javascript

ctx.fillStyle работает на первой строчке,но не работает в коце кода

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas.getContext){
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


    ctx.fillStyle='white';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(0,55);
    ctx.lineTo(40,25);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();


  }
}
```

Comment: То есть наоборот. Почему так?

Comment: О,спасибо)спасибо

Comment: )) Не дочитал пример, ctx.fillStyle отработает везде, до fill()

Comment: О,спасибо)спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример, red сработает до fill и green уже не участвует в процессе рендеренга

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

if (canvas.getContext) {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(0, 55);
  ctx.lineTo(40, 25);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas >
```

Comment: Ок,я понял,буду знать)